# How to add hang/timeout control of spawnSync in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Trying to use `spawnSync` to issue `ping` and `traceroute` commands:

```
export const exec = async (cmd, address) => {

    const result = child_process.spawnSync(cmd, [address]);

    let ret = {
        status: result.stdout.length === 0 ? false : true,
        message: result.stdout.length === 0 ? result.stderr.toString() : result.stdout.toString()
    };

    console.log(ret);
}
```

Depending on the address, if invalid, spawn hangs.

I've tried on terminal:

```
$ ping -c 3 123
PING 123 (0.0.0.123): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

This hangs (using MacOs) and never returns, locking the terminal.

So, how can I timeout the `spawnSync`, forcing killing the process and returning after some time with an error?